# RegExp Object - Run-time error '5017' - No apparent pattern issues

Tags: excel, regex, vba, vbscript

I am using the RegExp Object to parse a common text field and turn it into a number. I have the pattern: `(^[^0-9+-]+)|((?<=[+-])[^0-9]+)|((?<=[0-9])[^0-9.]+)` which should turn an input like `"37,080 lbs"` into `37080`.

For some reason, when I attempt to do this, I get Run-time error '5017'. I saw another post where the issue was caused by an error with the pattern, but I do not see any issues with my pattern and testing it out on a site like https://regex101.com/ shows that the pattern is valid.

Here is a sample script that illustrates this error:

```vb
Function Example()
    Dim Regex As Object
    Set Regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    With Regex
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = False
        .Pattern = "(^[^0-9+-]+)|((?<=[+-])[^0-9]+)|((?<=[0-9])[^0-9.]+)"
    End With
    
    Debug.Print Regex.Replace("37,080 lbs", "")
End Function
```

Note: I tagged VBScript because I am using the VBScript.RegExp Object. The code itself is VBA 6.5.1020 being run in Excel 2007.

Comment: regex101 is not comatible with VBScript/VBA regex flavor where you cannot use lookbehinds.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Which parts are different? Do you have a suggested pattern that I can use with the `VBScript.RegExp` Object to mimic the effect of what I currently have?

Comment: Yes, replace `^[^0-9+-]+|([+-])[^0-9]+|([0-9])[^0-9.]+` with `$1$2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace all occurrences of this pattern:

```
^[^0-9+-]+|([+-])[^0-9]+|([0-9])[^0-9.]+
```

with

```
$1$2
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MWdHhN/1).

Instead of lookbehinds (`(?<=...)`) that are not supported by VBA regex engine, you can use capturing groups, and restore the captured texts in the result with backreferences to the captured values.

Comment: Thank you! The Run-time error '5017' must have been because of the lookbehinds which were not supported by the VBScript.RegExp Object. After removing them, and using your suggested pattern, the code no longer raises any error. Great answer!

Comment: @Toddleson I must add that this workaround is easy because you removed the regex matches. Repacing and extraction are not always that easy and splitting is usually the hardest.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew being picky, but technically VBA doesn't have a RegEx Engine, it's pulled in from the VBScript Run-time via COM.